# Why doesn't this 'Wait until page contains' work as specified?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

```
wait until page contains  Takaisin

click button  QBackLink
```

This only gives 'Text Takaisin didn't appear in 5 seconds' message. No difference if I put 'Sleep 10s' before that. Any ideas why?? Button with text 'Takaisin' is visible and enabled.

```
<button id="QBackLink" class="btn btn-large pull-left" data-set-qindex="27" data-set-oid="zl75rd7u">Takaisin</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Wait Until Element Is Visible` instead of `wait until page contains`

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath=//button[@id='QBackLink' and text()='Takaisin']   20
Click Element                   xpath=//button[@id='QBackLink' and text()='Takaisin']
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: "Element 'xpath=//button[@id='QBackLink' and text()='Takaisin']' not visible after 20 seconds"

Comment: Then need to check your url?is it possible to share??

Comment: No, sorry… What is it that should be found there?

Comment: Check if there any `iframe` available?? If there you need to switch to `iframe.`